Как установить свой id в папке flask_session
Я сохраняю сессию в папке flask_session. В папке flask_session формируется свой id. Как поменять наименование папки я сообразил (SESSION_FILE_DIR='my_folder'), а вот id не получается поменять.
from flask import  Flask 
from flask_session import Session

SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
DEBUG = True
THREADED = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SUPPORTS_CREDENTIALS = True
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 5011
# SESSION_FILE_DIR = 'my_folder'

app = Flask(__name__)
 
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE=SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE,
)
Session(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

Результат
Папка - flask_session в ней файл 2029240f6d1128be89ddc32729463129

Как мне например сделать так
Папка - flask_session в ней файл 202402A

Вопрос как формировать id session самому средствами flask

Так делать категорически нельзя, id не просто так делают длинными и непонятными - если они будут короткими и/или понятными, злоумышленники смогут их угадать и украсть чужие аккаунты

Согласен с вами. Однако, мне необходимо формировать свой id. В данном примере, я показываю, что хочу менять id. Иными словами, вопрос не понятности id, а как его менять самому средствами flask session.
